# ASP NET Core TypeFilter properties are not set with filter attribute provided values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I created a `TypeFilter` chained to an `ActionFilter`.

The `TypeFilter` purpose is to be used in an `Action` of a `Controller`.
The `TypeFilter` has some required properties (asked in the constructor) and some optionals parameters.
But as there are some optional properties and probably will be more in the future, creating constructor to support every combination is not a chance. In order to solve that, I created public properties in the TypeFilter to be able to set them in the attribute as the next example:

```
        [HttpGet]
    [TypeTestFilter(typeof(WeatherForecast), "myparam1", "myparam2", "myparam2", MaxValue = 10, MinValue = 1)]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

The `TypeFilter`example code is the following one:

```
public class TypeTestFilter : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public int MaxValue { get; set; }

        public int MinValue { get; set; }

        public TypeTestFilter(Type type, params string[] parameterNames) : base(typeof(TypeTestActionFilter))
        {
            this.Arguments = new object[]
            {
                type,
                parameterNames,
                MaxValue,
                MinValue
            };
        }

        private class TypeTestActionFilter : IActionFilter
        {
            private readonly Type _type;
            private readonly string[] _parameterNames;
            private readonly int _maxValue;
            private readonly int _minValue;

            public TypeTestActionFilter(Type type, string[] parameterNames, int maxValue, int minValue)
            {
                _type = type;
                _parameterNames = parameterNames;
                this._maxValue = maxValue;
                this._minValue = minValue;
            }

            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
                // code.
            }

            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {
                // code.
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, `type` and `parametersNames` are parameters of the constructor. When the `TypeTestActionFilter` is executed, both parameters are set with the values correctly. But both `MaxValue` and `MinValue` property values are not set. They just have the default value for integer (0).

What Am I missing here? Why are these properties not set with the `TypeFilterAttributes` provided values in the `Action` of the `Controller`?

I can upload the example project if needed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, an attribute specification such as:

`[TypeTestFilter(typeof(WeatherForecast), "myparam1", "myparam2", "myparam2", MaxValue = 10, MinValue = 1)]`

equals:

```
TypeTestFilter anonymousObject = new TypeTestFilter(typeof(WeatherForecast), "myparam1", "myparam2", "myparam2");  
anonymousObject.MaxValue = 10; 
 anonymousObject.MaxValue = 1;
```

That means we couldn't get the max and min value inside the TypeTestFilter's construct method, since they aren't setting.

To solve this issue, you should pass the max and min value into the construct method like this:

```
    public TypeTestFilter(Type type , int minvalue, int maxvalue, params string[] parameterNames) : base(typeof(TypeTestActionFilter))
    {
        this.Arguments = new object[]
        {
            type,
            parameterNames,
            maxvalue,
            minvalue
        };
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brando Zhang. This confirms my theory. Anyways, as I said in the question. Having a constructor for every combination is not an option. Those two values are actually optional so I need three different constructor methods to support them. One without MinValue, another one without both MinValue and MaxValue, and another one with both. If I add another optional parameter, I will have to support those 3 combinations with the new one. And if for example I add another int parameter, I will have a compilation error because the parameter types are the same. Is there any workaround?

Comment: In my opinion, we could set a specific value as the optional parameter. For example, if the min is -1 means it doesn't contains value. We could create another logic inside the OnActionExecuting method according to your requirements.